# org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Unsupported color depth

Tags: java, swt

I have created a sample SWT application. I am uploading few images into the application. I have to resize all the images which are above 16x16 (Width*Height) resolution and save those in separate location.

For this reason I am scaling the image and saving the scaled image to my destination location. Below is the piece of code which I am using to do that.

Using `getImageData()` to get the image data and to save I am using ImageLoader `save()` method.

```
final Image mySampleImage = ImageResizer.scaleImage(img, 16, 16);
final ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader();
imageLoader.data = new ImageData[] { mySampleImage.getImageData() };
final String fileExtension = inputImagePath.substring(inputImagePath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
if ("GIF".equalsIgnoreCase(fileExtension)) {
    imageLoader.save(outputImagePath, SWT.IMAGE_GIF);
} else if ("PNG".equalsIgnoreCase(fileExtension)) {
    imageLoader.save(outputImagePath, SWT.IMAGE_PNG);
}
```

ImageLoader `imageLoader.save(outputImagePath, SWT.IMAGE_GIF);` is throwing the below exeception when I am trying to save few specific images (GIF or PNG format).

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Unsupported color depth
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4533)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.image.GIFFileFormat.unloadIntoByteStream(GIFFileFormat.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.image.FileFormat.unloadIntoStream(FileFormat.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.image.FileFormat.save(FileFormat.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageLoader.save(ImageLoader.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageLoader.save(ImageLoader.java:259)
    at mainpackage.ImageResizer.resize(ImageResizer.java:55)
    at mainpackage.ImageResizer.main(ImageResizer.java:110)
```

Let me know If there is any other way to do the same (or) there is any way to resolve this issue.

Comment: The GIF save will only save an image with a color depth of 1, 4 or 8 and with an indirect palette. If your `ImageResizer` is producing some other format you will have to convert it.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you for the info. I am currently using only 2 formats i.e., GIF and PNG and based on the file type ImageResizer will convert to the respective image type. It is not producing some other format.

Comment: By 'format' here I mean the exact values of the fields in the `ImageData` you are giving to `ImageLoader`. The exception you are getting is because the value of the `ImageData.depth` field is not 1, 4 or 8.

Comment: @greg-449 I have checked the depth in image data of my scaled image and that is 32 which is the reason for this exception. Any workaround is available for this situation?

Comment: You either have to fix the resizer to maintain the palette and color depth or you have to write code to convert the resized image back to an indexed palette based image with the correct color depth - I don't know of any SWT code to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got a solution by referring to this existing eclipse bug [Unsupported color depth eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=70949). 
In the below code i have created a PaletteData with RGB values and updated my Image Data.

My updateImagedata() method will take the scaled image and will return the proper updated imageData if the image depth is 32 or more.

```
private static ImageData updateImagedata(Image image) {
        ImageData data = image.getImageData();
        if (!data.palette.isDirect && data.depth <= 8)
            return data;

        // compute a histogram of color frequencies
        HashMap<RGB, ColorCounter> freq = new HashMap<>();
        int width = data.width;
        int[] pixels = new int[width];
        int[] maskPixels = new int[width];
        for (int y = 0, height = data.height; y < height; ++y) {
            data.getPixels(0, y, width, pixels, 0);
            for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
                RGB rgb = data.palette.getRGB(pixels[x]);
                ColorCounter counter = (ColorCounter) freq.get(rgb);
                if (counter == null) {
                    counter = new ColorCounter();
                    counter.rgb = rgb;
                    freq.put(rgb, counter);
                }
                counter.count++;
            }
        }

        // sort colors by most frequently used
        ColorCounter[] counters = new ColorCounter[freq.size()];
        freq.values().toArray(counters);
        Arrays.sort(counters);

        // pick the most frequently used 256 (or fewer), and make a palette
        ImageData mask = null;
        if (data.transparentPixel != -1 || data.maskData != null) {
            mask = data.getTransparencyMask();
        }
        int n = Math.min(256, freq.size());
        RGB[] rgbs = new RGB[n + (mask != null ? 1 : 0)];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            rgbs[i] = counters[i].rgb;
        if (mask != null) {
            rgbs[rgbs.length - 1] = data.transparentPixel != -1 ? data.palette.getRGB(data.transparentPixel)
                    : new RGB(255, 255, 255);
        }
        PaletteData palette = new PaletteData(rgbs);

        ImageData newData = new ImageData(width, data.height, 8, palette);
        if (mask != null)
            newData.transparentPixel = rgbs.length - 1;
        for (int y = 0, height = data.height; y < height; ++y) {
            data.getPixels(0, y, width, pixels, 0);
            if (mask != null)
                mask.getPixels(0, y, width, maskPixels, 0);
            for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
                if (mask != null && maskPixels[x] == 0) {
                    pixels[x] = rgbs.length - 1;
                } else {
                    RGB rgb = data.palette.getRGB(pixels[x]);
                    pixels[x] = closest(rgbs, n, rgb);
                }
            }
            newData.setPixels(0, y, width, pixels, 0);
        }
        return newData;
    }
```

**To find minimum index:**

```
static int closest(RGB[] rgbs, int n, RGB rgb) {
        int minDist = 256*256*3;
        int minIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            RGB rgb2 = rgbs[i];
            int da = rgb2.red - rgb.red;
            int dg = rgb2.green - rgb.green;
            int db = rgb2.blue - rgb.blue;
            int dist = da*da + dg*dg + db*db;
            if (dist < minDist) {
                minDist = dist;
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return minIndex;
    }
```

**ColourCounter Class:**

```
class ColorCounter implements Comparable<ColorCounter> {
    RGB rgb;
    int count;

    public int compareTo(ColorCounter o) {
        return o.count - count;
    }
}
```